# Hosted an MVC Web app in IIS 7.5. Error while invoking the Office.Interop.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I am trying to open the Word file from the C# application and converting it into PDF. It works for me locally. It works for me when I host on the testing server.

I have the same setup on the live server and it is not working in live.

In live server, I try the below scenarios,

1. Re-Installed the MS Office. --> Didn't work
2. Installed the visual studio and debugged there locally the code works fine the live server when debugging.
3. When it is hosted and then tested on the same server with the localhost in the live server it didn't work.
4. When tested from the remote server also it didn't work.
5. I have tried to change the port numbers. I have tried by changing the application pools identity to local server etc.it didn't work.
6. Changed the DM Config office registry to an everyone access. Nothing changed the same issue.

I am banging my head for the last 2 days, no improvement.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly was the actual error you were getting? Without that, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: On your server check if you have Office.Interop.dll in  bin directory of your app

Comment: @Steve I am not getting any errors from that, there is no errors in the catch block, but it is not working. if i am taking the code to the server and debug it with the visual studio it is working correctly.

Comment: Resolved the issue : :) 
Gave permissions to the Office DCOM  and there were few folders related to office that has been created in C:/ and given permissions to that folder also. App Pools Identity also has been changed.